# Sending email to Gmail by Google - The response was: 550 relay not permitted

Tags: gmail

I have a .com and a .co.uk address that uses Gmail by Google (GSuite). The .com email address works fine but when I send an email to the .co.uk address, I get

```
550 relay not permitted
```

Any reason it should have suddenly stopped working? Has been working for several years. All DNS entries points to Gmail by Google

Domain is virtualfestivals.co.uk

I can send emails just fine. I am using a mix of Outlook (personal) and Google Chrome.

I've added SPF and DKIM records also.

The problem seems to be as follows:

- I can send to the .com address from work (non gmail) and my personal gmail addy
- I can send to the .co.uk address from work addy
- **I can not send to the .co.uk address from my personal email**
- I can send from the .co.uk address to the same .co.uk address
- I can send from the .com adress to the .co.uk address
- **I can not send from any other address on the same domain to the .co.uk address**

In summary, I can't email xxx@virtualfestivals.co.uk from an email hosted with Gmail but I can send it to xxx@virtualfestivals.com

Comment: Please edit your question and include information on what method you are using to send email from X to Y, e.g Outlook, Gmail GUI, Website Form, Host Server etc.

Comment: Done - mainly Google Chrome

Comment: "I have a .com and a .co.uk address that uses Gmail by Google." - Presumably you are using GSuite? You can't send email using "Google Chrome" per se, you would need to be using the Gmail GUI or a "website form" (as Simon suggests) or some other email client that runs _in the browser_?

Comment: I basically can't use a google based email (jo.bloggs@gmail.com) to email xxx@virtualfestivals.co.uk. However, I can send it to the .com equivalent. Doesn't matter which client I use.